# Show set of images based on random question

Tags: javascript, html

Very much a beginner here. I'm trying to expand on this spinning wheel game https://gist.github.com/jrue/a2aaf36b3c096925ccbf by adding sets of 3 images for the player to select (2 incorrect and 1 correct answer), however I'm at a complete loss.

I've tried creating an image array, then showing images based on the data.value (having changed the value), then appending them to the document body with no luck.

```
imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = "cat.jpg";

imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = "dog.jpg";

imgArray[2] = new Image();
imgArray[2].src = "cat.jpg";

imgArray[3] = new Image();
imgArray[3].src = "dog.jpg";

//show img based on question
function showImg()
{
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = data.value;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}*/
```

Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the question???????????

Comment: img.src = data.value;

What is data and where is it defined?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the gist you provided, your `data` is an array. While working with arrays, you need to access them through indexes. In your case, `img.src = data.value;` should be `img.src = data[0].value` where `[0]` is index of your desired field in array.

The best way to make this work is by having the img.src also in object with question, value etc.